# Icon does not appear for Outlook Web add in for Outlook 2016 on Windows

Tags: web, outlook, add-in, apps-for-office

I am developing a Web Add In for Outlook. I have specified the IconUrl for the add in. The add in appears in Outlook for Windows. However it loads the default icon instead of my personalised icon.

[image]

Here is my XML manifest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:ce44715c-8c4e-446b-879c-ea9ebe0f09c8-->
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
          xsi:type="MailApp">

  <!-- Begin Basic Settings: Add-in metadata, used for all versions of Office unless override provided. -->

  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. -->
  <Id>badb297b-b8e8-41e1-9513-ff821c15189c</Id>

  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>my company- Meetings</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Company" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Outlook addin"/>  
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:44373/Images/Icon80.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use add-in commands, defined in the VersionOverrides element of your manifest. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook). Specifically, the Resources element controls this icon.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I do have the resources element as follows - </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>        
        <bt:Image id="icon16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44373/Icon16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44373/Icon32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon64" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44373/Icon64.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="icon80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44373/Icon80.png"/>       
      </bt:Images>